# How to have two workers for heroku.yml?

Tags: django, docker, heroku, dockerfile, docker-container

I have the following `heroku.yml`. The 'containers' share the same `Dockerfile`:

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
    celery: Dockerfile
    celery-beat: Dockerfile
release:
  image: web
  command:
    - python manage.py migrate users && python manage.py migrate
run:
  web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT
  celery: celery --app=my_app worker --pool=prefork --concurrency=4 --statedb=celery/worker.state -l info
  celery-beat: celery --app=my_app beat -l info
```

I intended to have three containers, but it turns out that Heroku accepts only one `web` and the other should be `workers`.

So what do I modify at `heroku.yml` to have `celery` and `celery-beat` containers as `worker`?

**UPDATE**

I've changed the `heroku.yml` to the following, but Heroku keeps only the last worker (i.e. celery beat) and ignores the first worker:

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
release:
  image: web
  command:
    - python manage.py migrate users && python manage.py migrate
run:
  web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT
  worker:
    command:
      - celery --app=my_app worker --pool=prefork --concurrency=4 --statedb=celery/worker.state -l info
    image: web
  worker:
    command:
      - celery --app=my_app beat -l info
    image: web
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The name `worker` isn't really important](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#other-process-types):

> No process types besides `web` and `release` have special properties

So just give them different names:

```yaml
run:
  web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT
  celery_worker:
    command:
      - celery --app=my_app worker --pool=prefork --concurrency=4 --statedb=celery/worker.state -l info
    image: web
  celery_beat:
    command:
      - celery --app=my_app beat -l info
    image: web
```

When you scale those processes, use the names `celery_worker` and `celery_beat`.

Comment: Is it possible to scale them using `heroku.yml` syntax? Or just via CLI or Heroku webpage?

Comment: @EduardoGomes, I'm not aware of a way to scale via `heroku.yml` and I'm not sure that even makes sense. `heroku.yml` tells Heroku how to build your app and defines processes that can run. It's a build-time configuration file. Scaling can be done at runtime and shouldn't require you to deploy new code. But if you know of a way to scale `worker` and `web` processes via `heroku.yml` it should work for `celery_worker` and `celery_beat` too.

Comment: Thanks! I will scale them via Heroku webpage. I will try creating addons at `setup` state though, to automate the process as much as possible!

Answer (score 1):

A better option is to **combine** the celery worker and beat in a **single worker / command** : (can only be done on Linux os)

```yaml
run:
  web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT
  celery_worker:
    command:
      - celery --app=my_app worker --pool=prefork --concurrency=4 --statedb=celery/worker.state -l info --beat -l info
    image: web
```